# Machine Learning: what if any one of feature have no correlation with label(target)?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

If I had some data and tried to learn these datas in basic `Machine Learning` regression algorithm (`Linear regression`, `SVM`, etc).

But if any one of features have almost zero correlation with target(`y value`), then should I use `Neural Network` instead of basic `Machine Learning`?

(I'm sorry this is not code-related questions but have no idea where I can ask this kind of question. Thanks)

Comment: 1st, there is no such thing as basic machine learning, and if it was, standard neural networks could be part of it (if you already include SVM in such group). 2nd, this doesn't have anything to do with choosing a classifier/regressor, but with data preparation. Simple solution is to remove the non-informative feature from your training/testing data.

Comment: @lmanol Luengo, what if all of features are not correlated with target? Do I have to remove all of these features?

Comment: Not really. Here is where your model plays a role. As @Stergios mentions in the answer, correlation implies a linear relationship, and if all your features have 0 correlation, then linear regressors will fail. The usage of non-linear models might help here (such as kernel-SVM or neural networks), but there are also other many factors that play a role in the task, such as the amount of data vs the amount of features that you have (rows vs cols). In short, the question is too broad, and problem specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correlation implies a linear relationship between the feature and the target. If there is some non-linear relation between these two, it's OK to get a zero correlation but still the feature could help the model.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But it can "help" not "directly affect", right? My opinion is that, these zero-correlated features "help" only when if there were at least one feature highly correlated with target. If there is no such a highly-correlated feature, those guys won't help. What do you think?

Comment: I won't agree on that. These uncorrelated features could directly affect the target variable in an non-linear way. Take a look at the Anscombe's quartet (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet) where 4 datasets show the exact same correlation but are very different with each other. I'd suggest to plot the target and each of these features and see if there is some relation.

Comment: @Stegois "non-linear way" means that I have to use non-linear model such as Neural Network or SVM so that it could cover uncorrelated features?

Comment: Correct. Or even tree-based algorithms like Random Forests and GBMs. For SVM you should try some kernel (i.e. not simple SVM with linear kernel).